# Jquery/css header shrink on scroll. Make text disappear and enlarge

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I am trying to add a nice header to my website that shrinks on scroll. It works...

```
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('#header_nav');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 350);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            }, 350);
        }  
    }
});
```

The only issue is I've been trying to have the text in the div disappear/minify.
IBM has done this on their own website : http://www.ibm.com/ca/en/

As you can see, Their logo shrunk, their text disappeared and their top text completely hid/or disappeared.

How would I edit the current code to do the same.
Here is a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PMgE5/

Will this code require css? Will I need to edit css properties? Which is more efficient? Maybe I should try using css animations or transforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just shrinking the header, you should swap classes with toggleclass  > https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

This way, you can make two classes, one for your "big" header, and one for the small header.

And you swap between thoses classes depending on the scroll state.

Comment: wouldn't that just swap the classes really fast without an effect? Its not going to look good... Could you give an example?

Comment: Look at this https://medium.com/web-design-tutorials/4694b254609e its the same way, with changing classes, demo here : http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-onscroll-animated-header

Comment: The animation is set in the css